# Can you retrieve a git repo after your hard drive has been wiped?

Tags: git, heroku

I just recently had a problem with my mac and they had to wipe my hard drive and restart my OS. I've been working on a [website](http://www.collegeinsideview.com/), and had it saved on my computer. I had been using git, but don't have it saved to Github.

Is it still possible for me to retrieve the files for the site?

Note: The site is failing, so it isn't as bad as it sounds if I can't get it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have pushed to Heroku you should be able to get it back. Heroku isn't a repository service, but it [does let you clone applications for convenience](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app):

> To clone the source of an existing application from Heroku using [Git](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git), use the `heroku git:clone` command.
>
> ```
> $ heroku git:clone -a myapp
> ```

Once you get your code back, I suggest you follow Heroku's advice and use a proper repository service:

> Heroku provides the git service primarily for deployment, and the ability to clone from it is offered as a convenience. We strongly recommend you store your code in another git repository such as [GitHub](https://github.com/) and treat that as canonical.

[GitLab](https://gitlab.com/) and [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) both provide free private repository hosting.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got this error though: `Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: @AdamZerner, you'll need to make sure you're using an SSH key that you've set up on Heroku (the same way you would to get `push` access). This is done for security. You might not want just anybody to be able to clone your source code.

Comment: I've found my SSH key. So how would I use it?

Comment: Actually, this seems like a Heroku question now, so I gave you the best answer and I'll email them. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamZerner, check out [Heroku's SSH key management page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys).

Comment: Yea, that's what they had me do. Following the instructions in that article worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

If you didn't push to an online repository, you won't be able to recover your lost files. Git is in the local filesystem unless you push.

Comment: I had pushed to Heroku. Does that help?

Comment: @AdamZerner, in fact it does help. Please see my answer below.